# Show that (P(X), ⊂) is an ordered set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

It makes intuitive sense to me, but I am not sure how to prove it.

The exact wording of the exercise is:

Let X be a set, and let P(X) denote its power set. Show:

1. (P(X), ⊂) is an ordered set.
2. (P(X), ⊂) is a totally ordered set if and only if X = ∅ or X = {a}.

If I know how to do 1., I think I would be able to do 2. alone without help.

---

I would know what to do if it were (P(X), ⊆) but I am confused, because:

It is not reflexive since A ⊂ A  for all A ⊂ P(X) is not true because of A = A.

I am not sure if it is antisymmetric since the definitions I found would not work because of similar reasons as above.

I do know it is transitive, however.

So what type of ordered set would this be, and how would I prove it? I would appreciate the help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Your confusion is understandable, and your ideas are correct. The misunderstanding is just in notation and conventions. Some authors use $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ interchangeably. Another thing is that you can formulate a partial order (ordered set, as you call it) in terms of $\leq$ or in terms of $<$. You can recover one from the other.

Comment: In this case: $(P(X), \subsetneq)$ is ordered in terms of strict inequality (so, in terms of $<$), and $(P(X), \subseteq)$ is ordered in terms of $\leq$ (which leaves open if you interpret $\subset$ as $\subsetneq$ or $\subseteq$). These orders are essentially the same thing.

Comment: Alright that clears some things up. So I would just prove it same way? For example, start with reflexivity. Saying for example:

For all A ⊂ P(X): A ⊂ A

So ⊂ is reflexive.